# Prevent listener from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I'm working on a script that listen to user clicks and define its type (either Simple,Link change or form submit), I'm doing this through Listeners, but the click listener is triggered with every click. I don't want it to fire when one of the other two is fired

I tried using `event.preventDefault` and then check using `event.defaultPrevented` still it's firing.

This is my click listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){  
if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
console.log('click')
})
```

this is my beforeunload event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('before unload');
})
```

And this is my submit listener:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).forEach((element,index) =>
  {
    const submitButton = element.querySelector('[type=Submit]');
      submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit clicked');        
  },true);
  });
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong to stop the first listener from firing?

Comment: You don’t want to prevent the default action, you want to prevent the event from _bubbling up_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @CBroe tried both, didn't work.

Comment: You can only prevent the event of the same type firing again on a higher-level element by stopping propagation. But you can not have elements of different types canceling each other. If you click on a form submit button that has a click handler, then that handler will be called when you click. It doesn’t matter whether you are reacting to any other events as well, that has no impact on the click event.